# Gson to get Json value for a pie chart using Highcharts

Tags: java, json, highcharts, gson

I am working on Pie Charts using HighCharts.

The structure of JSON i needed is

```
 data: [
            ['Firefox',   45.0],
            ['IE',       26.8],                
            ['Safari',    8.5],
            ['Opera',     6.2],
            ['Others',   0.7]
        ]
```

I am using GSON to convert this into JSON object.

I tried to add a class 'Browser' which contains

```
 private List browserName = new ArrayList();
 private List browserValue = new ArrayList();

// passing the browser class object to Gson
   gson.toJson(browser);
```

In graph I passed the data as

```
 data: [
               json.browserName,json.browserValue

        ]
```

But this didnt worked. How can I achieve the required JSON format when name and value is a list.

Answer (score 1):

I added some quotes and braces to make your json valid. Then, it's a matter of looping through your `data` key which gives you an array of arrays.

```
String jsonString = 
    "{'data':[['Firefox',45.0],['IE',26.8],['Safari',8.5],['Opera',6.2],['Others',0.7]]}";
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray data = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonArray();
for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    JsonArray dataIndex = data.get(i).getAsJsonArray();
    System.out.println(dataIndex.get(0));
    System.out.println(dataIndex.get(1));
}
```

I find it helps me to [visualize](http://jsonmate.com/permalink/5547b8f1aa522bae3683ee31) the json before writing code to go in and get values.